# Is there any way to retrieve coordinates from searched location in mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am using mapbox geocoder to search for a location in one of my mapbox project. I am able to implement the search functionality successfully but I am having hard time in extracting the selected address by the user from the list of searched/suggested addresses.

**Is there any way to get the coordinates of the searched place?**

I went through mapbox docs but only found an event 'moveend' which is fired when we fly to some location. So I am listening for that event and once fired, I am calling getBounds() function on the map. It somehow works but it doesn't give me the exact coordinates since getBounds() gives the South West and North East coordinates of the box. Can we get the exact coordinates of the selected place?

Below is the code I am using to search for a place.

```
initMapSearch() {
    var _this = this;
    var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({ accessToken: environment.mapbox.accessToken, mapboxgl: mapboxgl });
    this.locationObj = geocoder.onAdd(_this.map)
    document.getElementById('geocoder').appendChild(this.locationObj);
}
```

And this is my moveend event.

```
this.map.on('moveend', function() {
    _this.lat = _this.map.getBounds()["_ne"]["lng"];
    _this.long = _this.map.getBounds()["_ne"]["lat"];
});
```

Thanks in advance to the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to `geocoder.on('result')` which is passed the feature (and its location).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I tried doing that but it gives the array of search results and not the exact location which user searched and navigated to on the maps.

Comment: If you're not familiar with how to interact with an array or extract values from an object, perhaps you should start with a beginner JavaScript course.

Comment: I am sorry if I couldn't explain you the question clearly. I don't want the coordinates of all the searched locations but only one particular location which user clicked/selected from that list of suggested places. The problem with geocoder.on('result') is that it is called while you type for suggestions but not when user has selected one of the locations from the results. Any solution for that.

Comment: According to the documentation, `result` is "Fired when input is set". (As opposed to `results`, whose behaviour is like you describe.)

Comment: Yes it is Fired when input is set. But what I want is a functionality which is fired when the user flies to the selected location from the list. 

So, when you set something in an input, you get a list of 5 suggestions and that time geocoder.on("result") is fired. Till this point everything is perfect. Now from that list(length = 5) of suggested places say I clicked the third element, how to get the coordinates of that 3rd element.

Once user clicks that location, I want to open a satellite view at that location which I cannot do until I get the coordinates of that place.

Comment: The behaviour you're looking for is exactly the behaviour I experience with `on('result')`.

Comment: Thanks brother! I solved it finally, had to implement moveend function also once user changes his location to a searched location and results.center gave the result. A big thank you!

Comment: Hi @neerav94 could you please share your html and ts code to see how you solved this issue. I'm facing exactly same issue. thanks in advance.